# UEC - Can the Cluster Controller and Storage Controller be seperate systems?

Tags: eucalyptus, uec, ubuntu-enterprise-cloud

My department is implementing an Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud.  I have done the testing and am quite comfortable with the 4 pieces, CC/SC, CLC, WS, NC.  Looking at various documents below it appears the the Storage Controller and Cluster Controller (eucalyptus-sc and eucalyptus-cc) are always installed on the same system.  My question is this: can I install the storage controller and the cluster controller on separate systems?

1. http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusAdvanced_v2.0 the picture indicates that cc and sc are two different machines
2. http://www.canonical.com/sites/default/files/active/Whitepaper-UbuntuEnterpriseCloudArchitecture-v1.pdf P.10 1st paragraph uses the word "machine(s)"
3. http://software.intel.com/file/31966 P. 8 indicates the same separate architecture
4. BUT... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/PackageInstallSeparate indicates below that the SC and CC are to be on the same system.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes I believe CC is separate from SC and both can be installed on separate machines. The installer as shown on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/CDInstall on step-4 shows how CC and SC are completely separate roles

Comment: I think you are right but the documentation all linked above never shows that kind of abstraction. Only way to know is to try it.